# R sqlexecute wildcard

Tags: r, teradata

Using RODBCext (and Teradata) my SQL query often need to be restricted and is done so with a `where` statement. However, this is not always required and it would be beneficial to not restrict, but I would like to use a single SQL query. (The actual query is more complex and has several instances of what I'm attempting to apply here)

In order to return all rows, using a wildcard seems like the next best option, but nothing appears to work correctly. For example, the sql query is:

```
SELECT *
FROM MY_DB.MY_TABLE
WHERE PROC_TYPE = ?
```

The following does work when passing in a string for `proc_type`:

```
sqlExecute(connHandle, getSQL(SQL_script_path), proc_type, fetch = TRUE)
```

In order to essentially bypass this filter, I would like to pass a wildcard so all records are returned.

I've tried `proc_type` set to `'%'`, `'*'`. Also escaped both with backslashes and enclosed with double-quotes, but no rows are ever returned, nor are any errors produced.

Comment: If you are using wildcards then your query needs to use "LIKE" not "=".  For example, LIKE '%' would return all records

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use COALESCE to do this:

```
SELECT *
FROM MY_DB.MY_TABLE
WHERE PROC_TYPE = COALESCE(?, PROC_TYPE);
```

In the event that your parameter is NULL it will choose PROC_TYPE to compare to PROC_TYPE which will return everything.

As for your wildcard attempt you would have to switch over to an operator that can use a wildcard. Instead of `=`, `LIKE` for instance. I think you would end up with some oddball edge cases though depending on your searchterm and the data in that column, so the `COALESCE()` option is a better way to go.

Comment: This works great when setting the argument to `NA`, instead of `NULL`. I prefer this answer over the `LIKE` solution @David Cram suggested, which also works but took significantly longer, because it also handles multiple `PROC_TYPE`s, even though it was not my original question. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad it did the job. While it's not a totally obvious solution, it's one that is good to remember as this type of scenario pops up pretty often in search logic and most RDBMS's support COALESCE. It also makes much prettier code than hobbling together ternary operators to return a `%` or some `if` logic to mush it all together.

Comment: @ajarr On my own, I just tried testing `sqlExecute` with the data portion set to `NA` and it seemed to work. But it's not clear to me what actual SQL code is generated when it encounters an `NA` value to substitute in. Do you have any insight into that? Also, given that the `NA` trick is [not documented](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RODBCext/RODBCext.pdf), I kindly request that you respond with your own answer using `NA` in the data's data frame in `sqlExecute`. Thank you!